# When I use vim-latex's F9 bibkey completion key to find matches for my citations I am getting "E121: Undefined variable: foundCiteFile"

Tags: plugin-vim-latex

I don't know how to provide a minimum working example, because this was working before on these files.  What *has* changed is that I updated to the latest version of Vim and moved my latex-suite installation to the new pack directory.

---

Much of vim-latex seems to work, but <kbd>F9</kbd> no longer works, instead several errors pop up, the first error statement is,

```
Error detected while processing function Tex_Complete[90]...Tex_GrepHelper[19]..Tex_ScanFileForCite: line 82:
```

After that there follow several instances of the error code

```
E121: Undefined variable: foundCiteFile
```

Then the final error that I see is

```
No bibkey, label or word beginning with 'partial_bibkey'
```

where I have substituted my partial bibkey with `partial_bibkey`.

---

Since BibTeX can find the files when I run it on the LaTeX file, I don't think that there is an issue with the setup, but something is wrong.  Can anyone give me some guidance on how to troubleshoot this?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You might have more luck on vim-latex's issue tracker on github